# vscode cannot use socks5 proxy?

Tags: visual-studio-code, proxy, platformio

clash is a socks5 proxy app.
vscode i use platformIO.

so i writing settings.json like :

```
"http.proxyAuthorization": null,
"http.proxyStrictSSL": false,
"http.proxy": "socks5://127.0.0.1:7890"
```

in platformIO_CLi CMD window,i type:
pio pkg install -g --platform "platformio/espressif32@^5.1.1"
but it don't work and cannot download anything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's unfortunately unsupported, you can only use a http proxy and convert it to socks5...